# PayPal Chained Adaptive Redirect with Store Logo

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

Do we have any documentation on how to include our Store logo in the PayPal Chained Adaptive Payment summary screen after it redirects from our Website? I've searched everywhere but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to include a call to [SetPaymentOptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/) after your initial Pay call.

You'll make the Pay call with CREATE as the action instead of Pay or PayPrimary.  Then you'll use the PayKey you get back in the SetPaymentOptions call right after that, and redirect to PayPal after SetPaymentOptions is done.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. But i had gone through this https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-create-a-paypal-page-style-6280  in my Business PayPal, now i'm able to see my store logo in Payment screen. Bored with Classic look.

Comment: Yes, that will work, too.  The method I outlined would let you set app specific details where-as what you've done is account specific.